# Converting JSON object to util.Date in Java

Tags: java, android, json, date, time

I have an object which looks like this:

```
{
    "date": 12,
    "day": 3,
    "hours": 12,
    "minutes": 32,
    "month": 8,
    "seconds": 32,
    "time": 1536755552909,
    "timezoneOffset": 0,
    "year": 118
}
```

I was using `util.Date` earlier to generate the date, but now I'm getting it in the format above from a Node.js server. How can I cast it to a `Date` type?

When I try to do

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
            JsonElement jsonElement = jsonParser.parse(response);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Date date = gson.fromJson(jsonElement,Date.class);

            lastLoadedDate = date;

            elapsedTime = 0;

        }
    }
```

This just fails because it's not a string,the Node server sends a JSON. If I do `new Response.Listener<Date>()` because it's a JSON, not a Date. Casting JSON to Date like this `Date now = (Date) myJsonResponse` causes Android Studio to error out saying:

> Incontrovertible types: cannot cast JSONObject to Date

Edit. I cannot use util.Date, because I need the time to come from the server, to be universal for everybody.

Comment: I think the `time` field represents the time in Epoch, cant you convert that to date?

Comment: If you want to get Date, exusively using json - you may try do this, using string format like "Sep 12, 2018 3:57:59 PM"

Comment: @AyushGupta This is what solved it. Would you like to add an answer?

Comment: @AlexIronside it's been a while since I worked with JAVA so I'm not versed with the syntax enough to give an acceptable answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what solved it. Thank you Ayush Gupta for the comment.

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try {

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                timestamp = jsonObject.getLong("time");

                lastLoadedDate = new Date(timestamp);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                //Handle the exception
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If possible, have the server return the date in a better format like [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) since that will avoid ambiguity and will result in smaller JSON payload.

If that is not possible, you will have to decide what parts of the JSON to use, either the `time` or the different values like `hours`, `minutes`, ... By manually picking out those parts, you can build a `Date` object manually using one of its constructors or via a `java.util.Calendar` object (since many constructors in `java.util.Date` are deprecated in Java 8).

Comment: The `time` field probably needs to be multiplied by 1000 for it to work in Android.

Comment: Probably true, and also depends if month is zero or 1 based to correctly interprete it. That is why I always insist on ISO-8601 to avoid all those issues.

Comment: Well just plugging in the `time` field should let Date work everything else out.

Comment: Only if you don't take time zones into account.

Comment: Doesn't Date have a Locale argument in one of its constructors? Or is that Calendar?

Comment: There is `setTimeZone(TimeZone timeZone)` on Calendar, not on Date.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate it yourself if you want to use java's util.Date.

In [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) you can find the proper contructor declaration as `Date(int year, int month, int date, int hrs, int min, int sec)`.

So you can create it from json, you just have to get proper values out of it (in a way that your json object is specifed-> in my example it is an Object):

```
Date date = new Date(jsonElement.get(year), jsonElement.get(month), jsonElement.get(date), jsonElement.get(hrs), jsonElement.get(min), jsonElement.get(sec));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you create a POJO class like this.

```
    public class ResponseModel {

    private int date;
    private int day;
    private int hours;
    private int minutes;
    private int month;
    private int seconds;
    private long time;
    private int timezoneOffset;
    private int year;

    public int getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public ResponseModel setDate(int date) {
        this.date = date;
        return this;
    }

    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public ResponseModel setDay(int day) {
        this.day = day;
        return this;
    }

    public int getHours() {
        return hours;
    }

    public ResponseModel setHours(int hours) {
        this.hours = hours;
        return this;
    }

    public int getMinutes() {
        return minutes;
    }

    public ResponseModel setMinutes(int minutes) {
        this.minutes = minutes;
        return this;
    }

    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public ResponseModel setMonth(int month) {
        this.month = month;
        return this;
    }

    public int getSeconds() {
        return seconds;
    }

    public ResponseModel setSeconds(int seconds) {
        this.seconds = seconds;
        return this;
    }

    public long getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public ResponseModel setTime(long time) {
        this.time = time;
        return this;
    }

    public int getTimezoneOffset() {
        return timezoneOffset;
    }

    public ResponseModel setTimezoneOffset(int timezoneOffset) {
        this.timezoneOffset = timezoneOffset;
        return this;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public ResponseModel setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Then convert your string response into `ResponseModel.class` like this

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
ResponseModel model = gson.fromJson(jsonElement,ResponseModel.class);
```

then create a method like below

```
private Date getDateFromResponse(ResponseModel model) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        //-----
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, model.getDate());
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, model.getMonth());
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, model.getYear());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, model.getHours());
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, model.getMinutes());
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, model.getSeconds());

        //OR
        //You can simply add this line with this time is equal to your all fields
        //And comment all above lines.
        //calendar.setTimeInMillis(model.getTime());

        return calendar.getTime();

    }
```

and simply call this method.

```
Date date = getDateFromResponse(model);
```

Hope this help you.